# How to define custom colors for heatmap in vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite

I need to paint heatmaps of certain range in certain colors, e.g.:

0-50 - red

50-150 - yellow

150+ - green

Also I want to add legend too.

I found some way to do first thing with conditional colors:

```
"color": {
  "condition": [{
    "test": {"field": "price", "gt": "50"},
    "value": "yellow"
  },
  {
    "test": {"field": "price", "gt": "150"},
    "value": "green"
  }
  ],
  "value": "red"
},
```

but I am not sure that this is right way to do it. Also I cannot add legend here.

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQmAE5JZEAGZsVCNAG1QmmoMxwVaEABMkmBgkoQAngiZtBAAgCEAXh8eAcgBxAHkQoICQAF8AXSUAdxorejQAZgAGdKV4GjIsNABGTKUbTBRUUAYVQUtSpE5MNigAawhKKAhiaKVkFWbLFTgoTEUQKDljMjRgKKU4WXGrGlkpipAAD2nlGgQ4AFVZOksnOCRdOXpSuFHjOEErWttrpUwnHGv0HSXZJBqXukEHxAABUds8QEh1jQIFttLpbJYAKQATVGgiQTDuAEEVoC0FkQOjMYIQqRqkgcGhNL8IHAlES7gBhdw6LbjWRLTDseRrMwQEa8sEHI7oBAXGBXG40O4PdDEX4McFwACODF+WzFshSqAKJSehSisxA8sEissTHRLW6xoVH1kDEEgiNXJazMErLW7M53K2fIFoC5u2FApAmsu+qUt3ulhNZrmqvVazDMEKerMBqNsaBFqQVsztrQ9sdhqN43dFk9cm9cgMAbg-Nh0uj6BwKhoUHBZBDAFZ0tas8c7u74t06w21lHZSBW+3OyGCr3+wX0GRBvNonEbaagYMHvTyPNZTMjU5GzLLM5XO5Rq93pZZGwEMt1f9MHjUEWnYagA

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a calculate transform along with a scale domain/range. The transform would look something like this:

```json
"transform": [
  {
    "calculate": "datum.price < 50 ? '0-50' : datum.price < 150 ? '50-150' : '>150'",
    "as": "binned_price"
  }
],
```

and the color encoding would look like this:

```json
"color": {
  "field": "binned_price",
  "type": "nominal",
  "scale": {
    "domain": ["0-50", "50-150", ">150"],
    "range": ["yellow", "green", "red"]
  }
},
```

You can see the full chart in the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQmAE5JZEAGZsVCNAG1QmmoMxwVaEABMkmBgkoQAngiZtBAAgCEAXh8eAcgBxAHkQoICQAF8FUCgkQSgGQVs4Sxs7BxwVGig4DwAeDwBWAAYPAH5A0v4ygI9UDwz7Smzc-KKARjLKwLL+btL6xoCAPkHIpSQISyYaWVk4KwB9NrzogF0lAHcaK3o0AGZS0qV4GjIsNE6TpQyUVFAGFUF02yROTDYoAGsISigEGI0SUyBUP0sKjgUEwihAUDkxjIaGAMRAcFkCKs82RjxAAA8UcoaAg4ABVWR0SxOOBIXRyegZNJKYxwQRWN5mOGYJw4NLoHTY2QJbl0QT8kAAFRJzJASHxNBmeO0ulslgApABNOEpJhsgCCsjI4rQpxAurZIVILyQODQmgSEDgSgtggAwu4dESEbJsZh2PI8WYILCgzKKVT0AgGTAmXDWezLMQEgxZXAAI4MEV46OyA6oTp3VLXKJo5OCVOzFK-EEgcuV1CyZKCNH+34ewRevE+v0BonB0Ogf2kiOhkC5xnFlk0Nkc9D1tOZ7OgCcwa5FrkF0tKBdVpA1ssp-lNwQt7fwz0WZUzxPoOYLJarHLrJQ8vmWWRsBDzEVKaAJflQCsL8kHmAwQBqMo4X6QY4XGKCthANQjX5fQQBpU82G2OEyChDE4ShDkNnPJwiQTOcQGcVx3G5XkJU-b9hVeV8xWPZtSyiIA):

[image]